# Angular Date filter is not workig in firefox

Tags: angularjs, date, nan

I am using date filter to format my date in my angular application.

In Firefox, I'm getting the date value as

> undefined NaN, NaN NaN:NaN:NaN PM

In Chrome its works perfectly as

> Jun 25, 2014 7:22:47 AM

My code is as follows.

```
var formatDate = new Date(info.list[i].date);
var newDate=$filter('date')(formatDate, 'medium');
```

How do I get it to work in Firefox?

Comment: Which version of Firefox is this?

Comment: The behaviour you're seeing is similar to trying to format an undefined date (see http://plnkr.co/edit/DOYda9RCyYCzLn0gV48G?p=preview). Could there be something else that is causing `info.list[i].date` to be undefined when you're testing? The filter works fine for actual dates in Firefox on the plnkr, at least on 29.0.1

Comment: Thnx for quick response ivarni but I had verified ...info.list[i].date is not undefied and I am getting response for Chrome browser

Comment: @dip could you post the exact value that `info.list[i].date` is set to?

Answer (score 8):

I ran into this issue and found that the problem was Chrome/Opera and Firefox/Safari have different tolerances for creating a new Javascript Date object.

This works in Chrome and Opera, but not Firefox and Safari:

```
var myDate = new Date("2014-08-12 11:46:26.509")
```

This works in all mentioned browsers:

```
var myDate = new Date("2014-08-12T11:46:26.509")
```

Once I had a proper Date object created, the AngularJS date filter works as expected.

Comment: Worked like a charm, amazing!

Answer (score 2):

There is a [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) library that facilitates dates parsing and that works cross-browser.

I also had a problem with `NaN`s in firefox and I was using

```
var myDate = Date.parse(date);
```

for Date creation. Switched to:

```
var myDate = moment(date).toDate();
```

and everything works flawlessly.