# AngularJS Date filter firefox/safari issues

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I'm having issues getting a date to display properly in Firefox and Safari, using a custom filter which supports day suffixs. I get the UTC date in the format:

`yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss`

I then have a custom `DateFilter`, which replaces `oo` with a suffix, i.e. `2nd`:

```
var suffixes = ["th", "st", "nd", "rd"];

return function(input, format) {
    input = new Date(input).getTime();
    var dtfilter = $filter('date')(input, format);
    var day = parseInt($filter('date')(input, 'dd'));
    var relevantDigits = (day < 30) ? day % 20 : day % 30;
    var suffix = (relevantDigits <= 3) ? suffixes[relevantDigits] : suffixes[0];

    return dtfilter.replace('oo', suffix);
};
```

This works on Chrome, I pass the following into my template, and get the expected date:

`{{ date.date_utc | DateFilter:'EEEE MMMM doo yyyy' | uppercase }}` =
`SATURDAY NOVEMBER 1ST 2014`

On Firefox/Safari this is returned as:

`UNDEFINED UNDEFINED NANTH 0NAN`

Research from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24545181/angular-date-filter-is-not-workig-in-firefox) and [here](http://biostall.com/javascript-new-date-returning-nan-in-ie-or-invalid-date-in-safari) suggest I need to pass the ISO time, or a timestamp into my `Date` object.

I seem to already be doing this via `.getTime()`. I've also tried `.toISOString()`, but this doesn't even return anything in Firefox/Safari!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems Firefox/Safari doesn't parse `.toISOString()` into the 'correct' format...

```
input = input.replace(/(.+) (.+)/, "$1T$2Z");
input = new Date(input).getTime();
```

This now parses it into a correct ISO format, and then is successfully parsed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing the date in this format: `2021-01-29 12:10:58` safari will throw an error.

It must be in this format: `2021-01-29T12:10:58`